# character set changing or what?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, character, special-characters

I am a bit confused about this topic. Same sentences's google result could be different?

```
peоple in thе wоrld
```

At first you can search the firts sentence at google and look at the result. And after

```
people in the world
```

Seacrh second sentence and notice the differents.

How could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dump it as hex, you can see the difference. I just ran it through xxd.

The first sentence:

```
0000000: 7065 d0be 706c 6520 696e 2074 68d0 b520  pe..ple in th..
0000010: 77d0 be72 6c64 0a                        w..rld.
```

The second sentence:

```
0000000: 7065 6f70 6c65 2069 6e20 7468 6520 776f  people in the wo
0000010: 726c 640a                                rld.
```

This one appears to be valid ASCII.

Both look very similar, but instead the first sentence uses the unicode character set and uses Cyrillic characters instead of normal ASCII ones.

Comment: Sorry but i dont get it. How can translate text to hex and again translate to text and seen diffent?

Comment: The `o` in people is not the same `o` as it is in the second sentence. The `o` that is being used is actually the [unicode Cyrillic letter o](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/43e/index.htm) instead of a regular ASCII `o`. They just look very similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So a little script can do it?

Comment: I think there are scripts out there, but you can usually just copy and paste substitution. Usually people do this to bypass spam filters since the spam filters only look for the ASCII versions.

Comment: Thanks again. I have one more question; What else can use instead of a regular ASCII, and how did you notice this is "Cyrillic character" from hex?

Comment: You can look at [the Wikipedia page on unicode characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) for alternatives to ASCII. You can tell because regular ASCII takes one byte per character (`6f`), whereas the unicode characters uses up more than one (`d0be`).